# How to enable Yubikey 2FA using pam_u2f, for gnome desktop privilege elevation?

Tags: gnome, sudo, two-factor-authentication

Yubico's own docs do a pretty great job of documenting the process for enabling 2FA for pretty much every privilege escalation scenario (sudo from a terminal, gdm login, etc.):

https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016649099-Ubuntu-Linux-Login-Guide-U2F

However, they don't cover the full-screen privilege escalation overlay that appears when you do something on the desktop that requires higher privileges. This is a glaring omission for the application of system-wide 2FA from their docs. I'm hoping someone here might know how to enable 2FA using pam_u2f for this use case? Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: Seems like that is a question you should be asking yubico support.

Answer (score 2):

The file you want to edit is `/etc/pam.d/polkit-1`

Adding your auth statement in this file will allow Yubikey prompts on auth dialogs such as using the package manager or partition manager for example.

Comment: On my system there was no `/etc/pam.d/polkit-1` but I just copied the `sudo` file (which includes the Yubikey auth module) and it worked.